# How to create a AES Cipher using 128 bit string contains 128 0's

Tags: java, encoding, cryptography, arrays

I am using the below code to create a 128 bit AES cipher,

```
String initializer = "00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000";

byte[] initializer2 = new BigInteger(initializer, 2).toByteArray();

String encrypt = encrypt(binary_string_firsthalf, initializer2);

public static String encrypt(String plainText, byte[] key) {
    try {
        SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
        byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes("UTF8"));
        String encryptedString = new String(Base64.encode(cipherText));
        return encryptedString;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

But the code is returning a exception saying invalid AES key length.
How to create a cipher using 128 0's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
byte[] initializer2 = new byte[16];
```

is all you need to initialize a byte array with the default value of 0x00.

---

Don't use a static predictable key such as all 0x00 bytes for actual encryption.